# Shopping cart price rule 2 for 1

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

If I use this kind of price rule in Magento (1.9.2.2)

Buy X (1) get Y (1) for free (the step is 1) within a certain category - the rule only applies if customer puts 2 products with the same SKU (article number) in the cart. But that isn't the point of setting up the rule (to be valid within a certain category) is it?

I want the customer to be able to chose any kind of product as long as it is within the specific category, and when 2 is in the cart, the rule should apply.

Isn't this possible in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should look like this:

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
    if TOTAL QUANTITY IS 2 for for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL of these conditions:
        Category IS ...
        SKU IS ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you go for this

**CONDITIONS:**
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE

Click +

Select ‘Product Subselection’ from drop-down

[image]

If **total quantity is** ... (put 2 instead of dots) for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL of these conditions

[image]

Click +
Choose ‘Category’ from drop-down and select needed category.

[image]

**ACTIONS:**
For the apply field we’ll be using ‘Buy X get Y Free’. Now we just need to set the ‘Discount Amount’ to 1 and the ‘Discount Qty Step (Buy X)’ to 1.

Moreover, you again need to indicate for which category this works for items added to cart.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Klettseb - and if I want get the cheapest for free, within one and the same category? Kind regards :)

Comment: Im not aware this functionality exists out of the box